# Slim giving me a 404 even though I added it as a route

Tags: php, mysql, slim

I am trying to build a simple api that just returns JSON from a MYSQL server. I want to implement the possibility that you can search with an id. This is my code:

```
// Load Slim
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$configuration = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
    ],
];
$c = new \Slim\Container($configuration);
$app = new \Slim\App($c);


$app->get('/leerlingen','ll_posts'); //Get all "leerlingen" posts.
$app->get('/docenten', 'do_posts'); //Get all "docenten" posts.
$app->get('/ouders', 'ou_posts'); //Get all "ouders" posts.
$app->get('/bedrijven', 'be_posts'); //Get all bedrijven posts.
$app->get('/ll/search/:id', 'll_search'); //Get info for certain id.


function ll_posts() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM leerlingen WHERE approved = 'true'";
    try{
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $posts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($posts);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}}';
    }
}
    function do_posts() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM docenten WHERE approved = 'true'";
    try{
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $posts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($posts);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}}';
    }
}
    function ou_posts() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ouders WHERE approved = 'true'";
    try{
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $posts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($posts);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}}';
    }
}
    function be_posts() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bedrijven WHERE approved = 'true'";
    try{
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $posts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($posts);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}}';
    }
}

function ll_search($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM leerlingen WHERE id = :id";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $names = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($names);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}

$app->run();


function getConnection(){
    $dbPost = "localhost";
    $dbUser = "a1070rik";
    $dbPass = "********************";
    $dbName = "portals";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}
```

And this is the page I'm trying to access:

> https://***********.io/api/v2/ll/search/11

All the folders paths are fine and the database connection works.

Hope someone has a solution.

**EDIT** added .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Did you setup URL-Rewriting? (.htaccess on Apache/PHP-Systems). Please have a look at the docs: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/web-servers.html

Comment: I edited it, is this what you meant?

Comment: Jep, thats what I meant. Did you try to just do an `echo 'hello world';` in the index.php? If that doesn't work, it's a problem with your server configuration. Did you enable `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` in the server-wide apache config?

Comment: Can you try to use the htacess that ships with slim ? https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/example/.htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Slim 2 and Slim 3 code. It seems you are using Slim 3.

`$app = new \Slim\App($c);`

However you are defining the route with Slim 2 syntax.

`app->get('/ll/search/:id', 'll_search');`

With Slim 3 the [named placeholders](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#how-to-create-routes) should be defined like the following.

`app->get('/ll/search/{id}', 'll_search');`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

I needed to add an older version of slim.

Still thanks everyone